# Returning the highest value java

Tags: java

I'm trying to search an ArrayList and find the highest student mark. The values are randomly inputted. I have written code that works *if* the values are in order. But when I try to enter values in a random order, the loop always returns the last value entered! (Which is starting to frustrate me a little as I thought it worked!) It's probably something simple but I have missed the point again.

One other note `.getName` retrieves the student name with the highest mark.

Here is the code:

```
public String top()
{
    int highest = 0;
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < people.size();k++)
    {
        if (people.get(k).getMark() > highest)
        {
            highest = k;
        }       
    }
    return people.get(highest).getName();
}
```

Comment: homework? if yes then tag it please

Answer (score 5):

You're setting `highest` to the *index* of the student with the highest mark, not to the highest mark itself. You probably want to keep both:

```
public String top()
{
    int highestIndex = 0;
    int highestMark = people.get(0).getMark();

    for (int k = 1; k < people.size(); k++)
    {
        int mark = people.get(k).getMark();
        if (mark > highestMark)
        {
            highestMark = mark;
            highestIndex = k;
        }       
    }
    return people.get(highestIndex).getName();
}
```

Note two other changes I've made:

- There's no point in declaring `k` *before* the loop; in general, it's tidiest to give local variables the smallest scope you can
- I've used initial values from the first person in the collection; this will now work with negative marks as well

Separately, you should think about what you want to happen if `people` is empty. (Currently the code will throw an exception.)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that highest is the index, so your if condition should be:

```
 if (people.get(k).getMark() > people.get(highest).getMark())
```

You can also store both the highest value and the index in two variables:

```
    int highestVal = -1;
    int highestIdx = -1;

    for (int k = 0; k < people.size(); k++)
    {    
        if (people.get(k).getMark() > highestVal)
        {
            highestVal = people.get(k).getMark();
            highestIdx = k;
        }       
    }
    return people.get(highestIdx).getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing indices and values.

Try:

```
if (people.get(k).getMark() > people.get(highest).getMark())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing what your variables represent. You're comparing the indivduals marks to 'highst', but then you're setting highest to equal the index of that person (k).

So you're comparing indexes with marks...

Answer (score 1):

`highest` is the index, you are comparing the mark to the index of the mark

```
if (people.get(k).getMark() > highest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing to highest in the loop you should compare to `people.get(highest).getMark()`

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra variable to hold the person's index.

```
public String top()
{
    int highest = 0;
    int k;
    int topPerson;

    for (k = 0; k < people.size();k++)
    {
        if (people.get(k).getMark() > highest)
        {
            highest = people.get(k).getMark() ;
            topPerson = k;
        }       
    }
    return people.get(topPerson).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :)

```
  public String top()
    {
        int highest = 0;
        int k;

        for (k = 1; k < people.size();k++)
        {
            if (people.get(k).getMark() > people.get(highest).getMark())
            {
                highest = k;
            }       
        }
        return people.get(highest).getName();
    }
```